# Jquery autoselect select options of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three select options drop down menus with class 'film', but the values are linked so that I have to select all to get result. In my case the HTML code looks like this:

```
<select name="sc30" id="sc30" onchange="autoSelect()" class="film">
    <option>Choose an option...</option>
    <option>---</option>
    <option>White</option>
    <option>Black</option> 
</select>

<select name="ij10" id="ij10" onchange="autoSelect()" class="film">
    <option>Choose an option...</option>
    <option>---</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option> 
    <option>Gold</option>
</select>

<select name="sc100" id="sc100" onchange="autoSelect()" class="film">
   <option>Choose an option...</option>
   <option>---</option>
   <option>Gold glossy</option>
   <option>Silver glossy</option> 
</select>
```

If I select **White** option from **id="sc30"** the other two select options must take a value **"---"**. Or if I select option **Gold glossy** from **id="sc100**" the other options from this class **'film'** must take this value **---**

I think that I have to use jQuery each() method. But how to check if any select option is selected and make other select options from this class with "---" value without already selected option. The code below don't work properly.

```
function autoSelect() {
   $('.dummy').each(function(index, value){
       if($(this).val() != '---') {
           $(".dummy").val($(".dummy option:eq(1)").val());
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('select.film').on('change', function() {
    var cb = $(this);
    if (2 === cb.prop('selectedIndex')) {
      $('select.film').not(cb).prop('selectedIndex', 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sc30" id="sc30" class="film">
  <option>Choose an option...</option>
  <option>---</option>
  <option>White</option>
  <option>Black</option>
</select>

<select name="ij10" id="ij10" class="film">
  <option>Choose an option...</option>
  <option>---</option>
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Green</option>
  <option>Gold</option>
</select>

<select name="sc100" id="sc100" class="film">
  <option>Choose an option...</option>
  <option>---</option>
  <option>Gold glossy</option>
  <option>Silver glossy</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : remove `onchange="autoSelect()"` from all select boxes and bind `change` event as shown below and select second `option` for each select box except the current one for which `change` event fired -

```
$(function(){
 $('.film').change(function(){
     //iterate all other select box except current using `not(this)`
     $('.film').not(this).each(function(){
         // get selected option for the current select box
         var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
         // if index of selected option is greater than 1, 
         // it means option is selected.
         if($selected.index()>1)    
           $(this).val($(this).find('option:eq(1)').val());
     });
 });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59jrxpab/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

I just remove these two rows code:

```
var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
if($selected.index()>1)
```

and already is ok!

```
$(function(){
 $('.film').change(function(){
     //iterate all other select box except current using `not(this)`
     $('.film').not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).find('option:eq(1)').val());
     });
 });
});
```